# Move between sheets with a cell reference (getSheetByName) ScriptGoogle

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I spent the last two nights without sleeping, because I can not solve this problem.
I want to create a macro, where I change the page according to the information of a cell.

ScriptGoogle

Cell A1 = Month. (January or february or  March, It is variable)

```
function ABC() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('A1'), true);
}
```

in Visual Basic (excel) we can do that using

```
Sub ABC()
Sheets([A1].Text).Select
End Sub
```

Please help me!

Comment: A custom function can't activate another sheets. But I suppose you can do something like this with a trigger `onEdit()`. It will activate a sheet with the name taken from a current edited cell.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the funny script that immediately activates a sheet with the name taken from a current edited cell:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet_name = e.value;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
  ss.toast('Jump to the ' + sheet_name);
}
```

I don't know your workflow, I suspect it makes sense to limit the script by some range or/and some special syntax. Otherwise there will be surprises constantly.

Answer (score 1):

#### Move to the sheet named in A1

```
function ABC() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getDisplayValue()).activate();
}
```